# Why internal linkage error when template defined in anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, template-specialization

Declare template in anonymous namespace lead to error `error: function '(anonymous namespace)::f<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > >' has internal linkage but is not defined`.

The codes are belowings:

```
    #include <type_traits>
    #include <vector>

    namespace {

    template <class T>
    void f(const T& data);

    template <>
    void f<int>(const int& data){}

    template <typename Iterable, typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Iterable>()))>::type>
    void f(const Iterable& data) {
        ;
    }

    }

    void g() {
        std::vector<float> x;
        f(x);
    }
```

I searched and found [Possibly Same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229122/is-it-proper-to-have-a-template-function-inside-an-anonymous-namespace-of-a-cpp), but it won't explain.

Update:
If I remove the anonymous namespace, the error turns to be `Undefined symbols for void f<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > >(std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > const&`.

Comment: Note that you have two overloaded template functions `f` with second one having two template parameters. `f(x);` will invoke `void f(const T& data);` which is indeed not defined anywhere.

Comment: I want the second one only accept containers. How should I fix it?

Comment: Just remove the one taking `int`, and consider just writing your code without the complicated `std::decay` part, it probably won't be necessary.

Comment: You should utilize SFINAE-based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two overloaded template functions `f` with the second one having two template parameters. `f(x);` will invoke `void f(const T& data);` which is indeed not defined anywhere.

I'll now sketch out a brief solution.

The most practical way is to use a helper class that's partially specialized, since template functions cannot be partially specialized.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

    template<typename T, typename=void>
    struct ff;

    template<>
    struct ff<int, void> {

        static constexpr bool specialized=true;
        static inline void func(const int &data)
        {
            std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct ff<T,
         std::void_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T>()))>> {

        static constexpr bool specialized=true;
        static inline void func(const T &data)
        {
            std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template <class T, typename=decltype(ff<T>::specialized)>
    inline void f(const T& data)
    {
        ff<T>::func(data);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> x;
    int y;
    f(x); // Result: vector
    f(y); // Result: int

    // Error:
    //
    // char *z;
    // f(z);
}
```

You still need a 2nd template parameter on the template function, for SFINAE purposes, and most compilers should optimize away the extra function call, on a moderate optimization level.